# Brouwer degree and homotopy invariance

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$. Following [Topological degree theory and applications](http://books.google.fr/books?id=3Dn91zDvvOAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false), we define the degree of $f$ with respect to some regular point $p \notin f(\partial \Omega)$ by $$\deg(f,\Omega,p) = \sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(p)} \text{sign}(J_f(x))$$ where $J_f(x)$ denotes the jacobian determinant of $f$ at $x$. In fact, if $f \in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$, $\deg(f,\Omega,\cdot )$ is locally constant so the degree of $f$ can be defined at a singular point $p$ by taking a regular point $q$ closed to $p$: $$\deg(f,\Omega,p)=\deg(f,\Omega,q), \ \|p-q\| < d(p,f(\partial \Omega))$$ A fundamental property is that if $H \in C^2([0,1] \times \overline{\Omega})$ and $p \notin H_t(\partial \Omega)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, then $\deg(H_t,\Omega,p)$ does not depend on $t$ (homotopy invariance).

My question is: how to prove it?

Comment: This does not quite address your question, but you might enjoy Erhard Heinz's exposition of degree theory in his classic paper, [An Elementary Analytic Theory of the Degree of Mapping in n-Dimensional Space](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/FULLTEXT/1959/8/58017), Indiana Univ. Math. J. 8 No. 2 (1959), 231–247 where a generalization of the result you ask about is proved in theorem 3.

Comment: @Martin: I found my answer in the paper you mention, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition 1.2.2 in [Topological degree theory and applications](http://books.google.fr/books?id=3Dn91zDvvOAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false) can be generalized without changing the proof:

> **Proposition:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set, $f \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and $p \notin f(\partial \Omega)$ a regular point of $f$. Then there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for any function $\phi : \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int_{\Omega} \phi=1$ and $\phi(x)=0$ if $\| x \|>\epsilon_0$, $$\deg(f,\Omega,p):=\sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(p)} \text{sign}(J_f(x))= \int_{\Omega} \phi(f(x)-p)J_f(x)dx$$

Then, lemma 2 and theorem 3 in [An elementary analytic theory of the degree of mapping in n-dimension space](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/FULLTEXT/1959/8/58017) can be proved in almost the same way; just use Sard's lemma to justify that $p$ can be supposed regular.

---

Another important detail: in Heinz's article, it is prove that we can take $\epsilon_0= d(p,f(\partial \Omega))$ whereas we don't know how evolve $\epsilon_0$ with $f$ in the previous proposition. However, such an information is needed to prove lemma 2. So we have to add some details about this point in the previous proof.